# CSS - Fit 3x3 Graphics to tile / scale within a div?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Assuming the image above is sliced into 9 separate images, is there any way to tell CSS3 to tile and scale a 3x3 graphic over a div?  Or is doing it with div or a table the only real way?

Answer (score 0):

If the parent element has the appropriate size, you can simply `float: left` all nine images inside it.